# Lambda code does not get zipped during `package` command when using substacks

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I am using CloudFormation for creating lambda functions. The lambda functions are stored in a separate file and then recreated using `aws cloudformation package` command. This works fine and the stack gets deployed successfully:

```yaml
# Filename: auth/auth.yml
# Lambda JS file: auth/lambda-pre-signup.js
Resources:
  ## Other resources here
  MyPreSignupLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Architectures:
        - arm64
      Code: 'lambda-pre-signup.js'
      Handler: 'lambda-pre-signup.handler'
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      PackageType: Zip
      Role: !GetAtt MyRole.Arn
```

Command:

```bash
aws cloudformation package --template-file auth.yml --s3-bucket my-bucket --output-template-file generated-auth.yml

aws cloudformation deploy --template-file generated-auth.yml --stack-name test-stack --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

However, when I create a root stack template and reference lambda, I get an error:

> Resource handler returned message: "Could not unzip uploaded file. Please check your file, then try to upload again. (Service: Lambda, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxxxx)"

When I check the S3 bucket for the uploaded file, the source code is there but it is not zipped (I can download and directly view the code without needing to unzip it).

Here is my current CF template for root stack:

```yaml
# Filename: root.yml
Resources:
  MyAuth:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: ./auth/auth.yml
```

Command:

```bash
aws cloudformation package --template-file root.yml --s3-bucket my-bucket --output-template-file generated-root.yml

aws cloudformation deploy --template-file generated-root.yml --stack-name test-root-stack --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM
```

Is there some option in the `package` command to make sure that the uploaded lambda code is zipped?

EDIT: Wrote a wrong argument

Comment: its not possible to get the error you are getting. `package` does not have  `--generated-template-file` argument, so it will not even make any zip.

Comment: @Marcin Sorry that was my bad. I wrote the wrong option in this question. You can try it with `--output-template-file`

Answer (score 0):

An official AWS [CLI documentation](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/cloudformation/package.html) clearly states that:

> If you specify a file, the command directly uploads it to the S3 bucket. If you specify a folder, the command zips the folder and then uploads the .zip file.

To make sure your file gets compressed you could create a new directory (eg. `code`) and place your `lambda-pre-signup.js` file there:

```
mkdir code
mv lambda-pre-signup.js code/
```

Then your corrected CloudFormation template could look like:

```
# Filename: auth/auth.yml
# Lambda JS file: auth/code/lambda-pre-signup.js
Resources:
  # Other resources here
  MyPreSignupLambda:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Architectures:
        - arm64
      Code: code/
      Handler: lambda-pre-signup.handler
      Runtime: nodejs16.x
      Role: !GetAtt MyRole.Arn
```

Side notes:

- I used `code/` to explicitly indicate the directory, `code` should work as well,
- there is no need for quotes in `Handler` and `Runtime` key values as per YAML specification,
- `PackageType` can be omitted.